# Дальше всё было (,) как обычно

Tags: пунктуация

Следует ли ставить запятую именно в этом предложении? В книге В.О. Пелевина "Чапаев и Пустота" в этой фразе стоит запятая.

Comment: Вполне может быть. В книге в принципе много моментов, на которые в современном русском языке, на мой взгляд, посмотрели бы иначе. Возможно, дело в редакции.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Слова «как обычно» не являются вводными и не обособляются, если они входят в состав сказуемого или тесно связаны с ним по смыслу.

*Грамота.ру*

Пелевинъ посчиталъ, что связи нѣтъ и поставилъ запятую —- имѣетъ право. Въ большинствѣ случаевъ знакъ ставится, оборотъ отдѣляется запятой.

> Вводное слово «как обычно», а также вводные сочетания «как обычно (в какое-либо время)» обособляются.

*Грамота.ру*

Answer (score 1):

Если "как обычно" - сравнительный оборот, то его, как и вводные слова, можно изъять и предложение при этом не "сломается". Но так не получается:
*Дальше всё было.* || Смысл нарушен, и так нельзя оставлять.

Интересно то, что в других книгах Пелевина это же предложение без запятой. То есть получается, что в "Чапаев и Пустота" действительно опечатка.

Если чуть поменять, то возможен сравнительный оборот:
*Уже всё было (произошло), как обычно.*